# Capture the collection type used in C extends Collection<R>

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to simplify down one of my methods, which uses some Java 8, but need not to use it:

```
public <T, U, R> Collection<R> singleCollectionOf(final Collection<T> collectionA, final Collection<U> collectionB, final Supplier<Collection<R>> supplier, final BiFunction<T, U, R> mapper) {
    if (Objects.requireNonNull(collectionA).size() != Objects.requireNonNull(collectionB).size()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    Objects.requireNonNull(supplier);
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
    Iterator<T> iteratorA = collectionA.iterator();
    Iterator<U> iteratorB = collectionB.iterator();
    Collection<R> returnCollection = supplier.get();
    while (iteratorA.hasNext() && iteratorB.hasNext()) {
        returnCollection.add(mapper.apply(iteratorA.next(), iteratorB.next()));
    }
    return returnCollection;
}
```

Now you see here that I need to supply a `Supplier<Collection<R>>` to be able to create the resulting collection.

Is there a way to capture, if and only if, the collection type of `collectionA` is equal to that of `collectionB` the type of collection that has been used and reduce the need to provide the custom supplier?

I would like to be able to call it like this, in pseudo code:

```
singleCollectionOf(ArrayList<T>, ArrayList<U>, BiFunction<T, U, R>);
```

and then it would need to be able to supply the `ArrayList::new` itself as supplier.

Is this possible? Is there a way to figure out the type of the actual object, and not the reference type, in case both are `ArrayList`, but stored with a `List` reference?

Clarifying example:

```
List<T> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<U> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
singleCollectionOf(list1, list2, ...);
```

Comment: I can think of no way to achieve this, despite some dubious sequence involving `collectionA.clone()` and `clonedCollection.clear()` ... Maybe someone else has an idea, though...

Comment: `<T extends R, U extends R, R>`?

Comment: I wouldn't try to do this.  Note that all the library methods provided in Java `Collectors` went ahead and accepted the `Supplier`.  (And not every collection type even _has_ a public constructor.)